# does the following matrix update law, converge? if so, to what?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A$ and $B$ to be arbitrary matrices (but you can assume some conditions on their norm),

We have

$X_{i+1}=AX_{i}A^T+B$,

We are looking for $X_{\infty}$ (if it exists). Does it converge, if so, to what? 
Or even if it converges to let's say $X^*$, how do you solve this matrix equation for $X^*$? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the theories about fix point iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$ then the iterations converge to the solution to the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)
$$
X=AXA^T+B.
$$
*Proof:* One can solve the difference equation directly
$$
X_n=A^nX_0(A^T)^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n=1}A^kB(A^T)^k.
$$
With $\rho(A)<1$ one has the estimate $\|A^k\|\le C(\rho(A)+\epsilon)^k$ so the series converges absolutely (exponentially) to
$$
X=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^kB(A^T)^k=B+\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^kB(A^T)^k=
B+A\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^{k-1}B(A^T)^{k-1}\biggr)A^T=B+AXA^T.
$$
P.S. Normally one uses the [Smith accelerated iteration method](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~lionelb/MVGC/html/dlyap_aitr.html) to solve it faster.

P.P.S. The Lyapunov equation is a linear system
$$
(I-A\otimes A)\text{vec}(X)=\text{vec}(B)
$$
which can be solved by the standard methods.

Comment: thanks, but i dont get your point by sayin "one hast the estimate...."

Comment: @ehsank There is a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Then the spectral radius $\rho(A) < 1$ iff 
$\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0$. The proof uses often the Jordan decomposition of $A$ (see the link). Alternatively, Gelfand's formula.